# Phonegap fixed position div during scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, angularjs, cordova

I'm using Angular and compiling to iOS with Phonegap. I need a `<div>` to scroll and become fixed when it reaches the top of the page, similar to this post: https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/.

This method works fine for desktop browsers and Safari on iPhone but breaks in Chrome on iPhone and the native (Phonegap) iPhone app. The `<div>` will keep scrolling with the wrapper and then after scroll ends, jumps to the desired position on top of the page.

Simplified HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <other-content></other-content>

  <div id="top-shelf">
    scroll to fixed position
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fixed-top-shelf #top-shelf {
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

And the JS to add the class

```
element.on('scroll', handleScroll);

function handleScroll() {
  var st = element.scrollTop();

  if (st <= 80) {
    element.addClass('fixed-top-shelf');
  } else {
    element.removeClass('fixed-top-shelf');
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, did you mange to solve this problem?

Comment: No, we never fixed this. And I've seen some other apps in the wild that display this behavior. So I do not know of a good fix out there, sorry!